# Get Firebase Token for Backend Testing

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am writing an application in which I would like to use Firebase for the authentication of any sort of back end calls. Is there a way for me to get a token through a CLI or `curl` for local testing without having to spin up a front end to get the token?

Comment: Try the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/).

Answer (score 12):

As a resume (to me and maybe others) from @James-Poag answer, use:

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=[API_KEY]' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-binary '{"email":"[user@example.com]","password":"[PASSWORD]","returnSecureToken":true}'
```

Where:

> - `email` (*string*): The email the user is signing in with.
> - `password` (*string*): The password for the account.
> - `returnSecureToken` (*boolean*): Whether or not to return an ID and refresh token. Should always be true.

The property `idToken` from response payload is the parameter you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Well i have made a front end one page html to generate dummy firebase ID token for your application, in case anyone needs it

[Firebase Token Generator](https://github.com/joardar-aditya/firebase-token-generator)

Answer (score 1):

They changed the link - see [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-email-password).

```
curl 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[API_KEY]' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-binary '{"email":"[user@example.com]","password":"[PASSWORD]","returnSecureToken":true}'
```

> In the example above, you would replace [API_KEY] with the Web API Key
> of your Firebase project, [user@example.com] with the user's email and
> [PASSWORD] with the user's password.